# jQuery modify image's parent a tag depending on image src

Tags: jquery, parent, attr

I have a page that loads an image at random. With jQuery, I'd like to check the image's `src` and, depending on what that src contains, modify the `href` of the image's parent `a` tag.

Here's what I've written so far, with no luck:

```
<div class="hero">
    <div class="inner">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://encompassomaha.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/copy-2.png" class="header-image" width="960" height="250" alt="" /></a>
    </div>
</div>



jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.hero .inner a img').each(function(i){
        var img = $(this),
        imgSrc = img.attr('src');

        if(imgSrc.contains('copy-2.png')){
            img.parent().attr('href', 'http://google.com');
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: could you post the HTML code? would be great if you could upload it into jsfiddle. I mean, if you are randomly taking a picture from a directory or a list you can save what you have chosen somewhere...

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RLQLh/ Updated answer w/ html

Comment: could you add the css? if there is a css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

http://jsfiddle.net/RLQLh/5/

and with http://jsfiddle.net/RLQLh/6/

with your selector

```
$('.hero .inner a img').each(function(i){
```

both use

```
if(imgSrc.indexOf('copy-2.pn') !== -1)
```

instead of string Contains()

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('img').each(function(){
        var img = $(this);
        var imgSrc = img.attr('src');

        if(imgSrc.contains('copy-2.png')){
            img.parent('a').attr('href', 'http://google.com');
        }
     });
});
```

Comment: I see, you just added the ```'a'```. I actually tried that too, but it didn't work either.

Comment: The jsfiddle doesn't work...Was it supposed to or are you just pointing out how it should be done?

Comment: Maybe it's due to the fact that Contains is not supported by all browser: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/contains